# Pytesseract fails to recognize '3'

Tags: python, python-tesseract, python-3.9

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, time, PADBS
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:/tesseract/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"

image = Image.open('3.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image))
```

[Image with '3'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkKY8.png)
[Image with '10'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzHm0.png)

When trying to read '3.png' it ends without output. But when trying to read '10.png' it reads it succesfully.
I have tried to run it on diffrent configs; --oem 3 -psm 13.
And i tried --oem 1 to 3. But nothing worked. What could be the possible cause that it fails to recognize this number? And what can i change in the code to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the page segmentation mode `6`:

> 6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
> [Source](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

For the version 4.1.1 the result will be 3.

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("3.png")

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry, config="--psm 6")

# Print
print(pytesseract.get_tesseract_version())
print(txt)

# Display
cv2.imshow("", gry)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stpoz.jpg):

```
4.1.1
3
```